# How to extract data from metadata(Varchar) in hive?

Tags: hive, metadata, extract

```
{"payment_charge_type":null,"ota_card_charge_attempt":false,"card_details":{"entity_type_card_charging":"OTA_BOOKING","token_number":"1bc5bea2-5281-4c98-bef6-18770d265fa7","entity_id_card_charging":"2115591871"},"payment_service_response":{"create":{"gateway":"ADYEN","request_id":"xxbn90apuglf2w92x9j6vpta","gateway_id":"1345702866109436","gateway_status":"Refused","status":"FAILED"},"verify":{"gateway":"ADYEN","gateway_txn_id":"1345702866109436","payment_txn_id":"xxbn90apuglf2w92x9j6vpta","bank_txn_id":null,"aggregator_txn_id":null,"pg_status":"Refused","status":"FAILED","pg_response":{"headerMap":{"Keep-Alive":["timeout=5, max=100"],"Server":["Apache"],"Idempotency-Key":["xxbn90apuglf2w92x9j6vpta"],"Connection":["Keep-Alive"],"Set-Cookie":["JSESSIONID=E4402846184CBE1F1BD0C68AB88A67F7.live4e; Path=/pal; Secure; HttpOnly"],"Content-Length":["196"],"pspReference":["1345702866109436"],"Date":["Sat, 05 Oct 2019 14:43:30 GMT"],"Content-Type":["application/json;charset=utf-8"]},"httpStatus":"OK","body":{"resultCode":"Refused","refusalReason":"Not enough balance","additionalData":{"recurringProcessingModel":"Subscription","visaTemplate":"SubsequentSubscription"},"pspReference":"1345702866109436"}},"bank_error_code":null,"bank_error_message":null,"created_at":null,"response_msg":null,"metadata":{"initiate_charge":{"display_message":"Not enough balance","via":"V2"}},"payment_mode":"CC","response":null,"crs_gateway":"adyen","card_data":{"token":null,"number":null,"type":null,"brand":null,"icon_url":null},"display_message":"Not enough balance"}},"card_data":null}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, it's completely unclear what you're asking. Be sure to provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise your question will have to be closed for being too unclear

Comment: Use json_tuple or GET_JSON_OBJECT+explode functions